# An approach to approximating the harmonic series.

Tags: calculus, summation

I would like to get help on the last step to approximating the harmonic series, here is my work:

Consider the equation:
$$f(x+1)-f(x)=g(x)$$

Through iteration one can come up with the solution:
$$f(x) = f(1) + \sum_{i=1}^{x-1}g(i)$$

If we consider the derivative of $\ln(x)$ we can easily see that for our purposes:

$$\ln(x+1)-\ln(x) \approx 1/x$$

And if we consider the recurrence relation:
$$f(x+1)-f(x)=1/x$$
the solution based on our formula is $h_{x-1}$ and a constant were $h$ is the harmonic series.

But let's replace $1/x$ with our approximation for it:
$$f(x+1)-f(x) \approx \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$$

Just by looking at this problem it's very easy to see that:
$$f(x) \approx \ln(x)+c$$
Thus,
$h_{x-1} \approx \ln x+c$.

And finally adding an extra term we get:
$$h_x \approx \ln x+1/x+c$$

My question is how would I know what value of $c$ will make this approximation as accurate as possible. I thought of using of derivatives to minimize the error but then immodestly realized that I can't as I don't have an exact formula for it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm currently  in high school, calculus I, so may you keep the terminology simple.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You might be interested in the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) $\psi(x)$ that satisfies $\psi(x+1) - \psi(x) = 1/x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you start on the path
of estimating
$f(n)
\approx \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
$,
this first leads to
$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)
\approx \int_0^n f(x) dx
$
with a bounded error term
if $f$ is monotonic.

When you do as you have said
and incorporate the derivatives
to reduce the error,
you may end up at the
Euler–Maclaurin formula.
One of many discussions
on the net is here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula